# How to find missing areas to explore?

Tags: guild-wars-2

While vistas, POIs, wps, hearts and skill points are listed and easily visible on the map, allowing a player to compare a fully explored map from the internet with his own map, this is not completely true for the concept of "areas", required for certain achievements split in Ascalon, Kryta, Maguuman and Shiverpeaks.

To get 100% map completion you don't need to explore every area, so it becomes hard to tell, in the end, which areas you missed while exploring.

What is then the faster way to see which areas are missing? Is it just a matter of looking manually for "blurs" in the map where you haven't been yet?

Bonus question: Will exploring different areas of the map with different characters on the same account add up in the achievement (like jumping puzzle, for example) or, like standard world completion, you have to explore them all with the same character?

Comment: im afraid you have to manually look for the area's which you haven't explored yet. For the bonus question you have to explore the map with every char (map completion or map exploring does not share between characters).

Comment: Additionally, you should know the /wiki command, such as "/wiki {place_you_wanna_map_of}" without the brackets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you: I already got 100% world map completion but I was still missing explorable achievements for Kryta, Shiverpeaks and Maguuma. For me, these achievements were ~95% complete with only a couple of missing spots.

Thankfully wall-scrapping is not necessary, unlike in gw1. What I found really helpful for getting those last few missing spots was to use [the gw2 wiki zone maps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Explorable_zone). Similar to Joetjah's suggestion, what you do is open one of the zone maps for the area you're missing and compare it with your ingame character's map. The gw2 wiki maps work very well for this purpose because:

- All the areas on a given map have a clear name on it. All these areas count towards the achievement so you have to uncover them.
- There are distinct white outlines that clearly show where and how much that area takes up on the map.

For me a lot of the missed spots were small areas usually off in the corner of the map that's easy to overlook. One example, I was at 174/175 for Kryta explorer. After exhaustively checking all the Kryta maps, turns out the one spot I'm missing is in Bloodtide Coast. It's the little segment all the way on the upper left corner of the map shown below:

[image]

Using this method it didn't take me very long to identify and uncover the other areas I've missed.

To answer your bonus question, all explorable achievements are account-wide; you only need to discover an area once on any character for it to count towards the achievement.

OTOH, 100% world map completion is per-character specific -- you get rewarded at the end for each character that completes it. This is important because one of the reward item is needed to craft a legendary weapon.

Comment: Well well... nice answer... :) (btw I knew about the map completion part for the legendary weapon, just finished a couple of days ago thanks to the new matchup system... :P)

Answer (score 1):

When you press M to see the map, and scroll out a bit so you can see the name of the zone, you can hover your mouse over it to see how much % you've completed on that map. That way, you can see which maps you still need to complete your achievement.

When you are in the map, you can see how many Vista's, POI's, Waypoints, Hearth's and Skillpoint's you still need. There is no way to check ingame where the exact location is: I had a few missing Vista's and even Hearth's which I didn't see on the map and found later on a part of the map that wasn't even blurred.

A thing I tend to do to find those last missing points, is to compare the map with [this](http://gw2.mmorpg-life.com/interactive-maps/). Just scroll over the parts of the map slowly and compare all the locations with your own map ingame. If you don't see them on your map, you've located your missing object!

If you want the full explorer achievement, you'll need to discover all 25 explorable [zones](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Zone) except Southsun Cove. A zone can contain [area's](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Area). Discovering areas in the zone is not required, and it's possible to have a map completion chest before visiting all areas.

Comment: Yep... this works well for hearts, pois, vistas and skills... but not with actual zones themselves... :)

Comment: @Frhay Are you sure you aren't confusing [Zones](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Zone) with [Area's](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Area)? If you want the full explorer achievement, you'll need to discover all 25 explorable zones except Southsun Cove. If you are talking about area's, discovering areas in the zone is not required, and it's possible to have a map completion chest before visiting all areas.

Comment: My fault! I was actually talking about areas, sorry... I'm changing my question right now to rectify this!

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way I know is to wall scrape, as you did in Guild Wars. As far as I know there is no method to work out which zones in the achievements you are missing.

You can also zoom out the world map just until the watercolour style overlays, then you can start to see which parts of the map are showing a brushed area, and which are clear. From this it's quite easy to see where the sharp contours of the edges go into these blurry/watercoloured/brushes areas. Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>LMB</kbd> to pop a waypoint on it and then you're all set to go exploring.

Comment: Wallscraping actually has no use really afaik. Even though I start with an outer circle and move inward all the time, I still tend to miss points who aren't on the wall but more inward. The last part of your answer sounds good though!!!

Comment: Yes, such areas as the jumping puzzle in Mount Maelstrom count as an area, but is only accessible through a portal spawned after an event.
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dierdre%27s_Steps

Comment: Is it safe to say that doing 100% normal map exploration + every jumping puzzle will discover every area? Or are there areas not linked event to jps? :)

Comment: Getting 100% map completion **will not** get you all the exploration achievements.

Comment: I know... :)... but 100% exploration plus jumping puzzles? :P